# Request/response process in Nest and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I am new in Nest and RabbitMQ. Could you please let me know how to build synchronous request/response process? And so that the producer would return data to consumer while ack. 
Producer is awaiting once promise resolved.
I would appreciate for an example.
Thanks in advance

Comment: RabbitMQ is an messaging system for facilitating asynchronous behaviour. Are you sure that's what you want? Are you building the bit that sends the first ("request") message, or the bit that sends the second ("reply") message?

Comment: Hello @Richard, thank you for quick response.
I am building a microservice stack and I want them communicate via RabbitMQ in request/response pattern and consumer would return data (smth like htttp(get) query)

Comment: So, in HTTP terms, are you building the client or the server?

Comment: Hello @Richard, Yeah, e.g Articles mservice will request user details from User mservice

Comment: Ok, so "both". Your design is an odd fit for RabbitMQ. That's a request/reply for a resource which is the definition a of (perfect)  fit for a REST service. I've designed and built many message oriented systems, and this isn't shaping up as a good one. If you wanted to alert users when they were mentioned in an article - THAT would be a good fit for messaging.

Comment: Yeah, @Richard, You are absolutely right. Just thoughts: Direct Reply-To feature looks attractive for this.

Comment: It sorta depends. What happens if the requestor is missing (crashed, busy, similar)? Be sure to set a TTL so it gets cleared off the server, the moment it's no longer relevant. the "Direct reply-to" is a nice addition - but probably not vital. YAGNI.

Comment: scratch that. I guess you found this, too: https://facundoolano.wordpress.com/2016/06/26/real-world-rpc-with-rabbitmq-and-node-js/

Comment: Thank you, @Richard for your thoughts. They are really helpful. Currently avoiding to implement request/response pattern via message broker.

Comment: Hello @Richard, found this module as well https://www.npmjs.com/package/@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq